# TOTAL_REVENUE by past quarter report in Trading View

Tags: pine-script

I want to find out how quarterly revenue grow up or down.

Here is a script looks:

**a = b / c,**

where
**a** - ratio of grow up or down;
**b** - TOTAL_REVENUE by current reporting period;
**c** - TOTAL_REVENUE by past quarter report.

I don't find how I can get the TOTAL_REVENUE from the past quarter report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values available with the [`request.financial()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request%7Bdot%7Dfinancial) function are available [here](https://www.tradingview.com/u/?solution=43000564727).

This code is an example using "TOTAL_REVENUE":

```
//@version=5
indicator("")

revenueGrowth(sym) =>
    quarterlyRevenue = request.financial(sym, "TOTAL_REVENUE", "FQ", gaps = barmerge.gaps_on, ignore_invalid_symbol = true)
    var float lastQuarterlyRevenue = na
    var float result = na
    if not na(quarterlyRevenue)
        result := nz(quarterlyRevenue / lastQuarterlyRevenue)
        lastQuarterlyRevenue := quarterlyRevenue
    result

plot(revenueGrowth(syminfo.tickerid))
```

[image]

Comment: Hey PineCoders, could you help me out on my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70594051/calculate-replicate-rsi-from-tradingviews-pine-script

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there is a simple way. You can create a var array and keep pushing the values from financials whiner they change. So, to look at history, you just need to refer the elements of array at certain index.